# aggregate raster with custom function fails

Tags: r, terra

I'm doing a pretty basic aggregation operation using `aggregate` from the `terra` package. The main idea is to calculate the percentage of pixels with values over the whole number using the following function:

```
nofun = function(x){ length(na.omit(x))/length(x) * 100 }
```

Unfortunately, `aggregate` fails under different conditions -even simpler- and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

First try:
aggregate(chm, fact=20, fun=length, na.rm=T) # w/o na.rm=T

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1
```

Second try:

```
aggregate(chm, fact=20, fun=function(x){ length(x) } )

Error: [aggregate] this function does not return the correct number of values
```

Same result applying the above-mentioned final function modified according to [this reply](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/892883), as follows:

```
function(x){ if(any(is.numeric(x))){length(na.omit(x))/length(x) * 100} else {NA_real_}}
```

Everything tested both in `terra` `1.4.22` and `1.5.12` on W10.

Comment: When asking an R question, please always include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
```

You can compute the percentage of cells that are not `NA` with a simple aggregate function

```
a <- aggregate(!is.na(r), 2, mean) * 100
```

Or, more efficiently

```
a <- aggregate(is.finite(r), 2, mean) * 100
```

But this also seem to work fine with your function

```
nofun <- function(x){ 100 * length(na.omit(x)) / length(x)}
b <- aggregate(r, 2, nofun)
plot(b, plg=list(title="NA (%)"))
```

[image]

By adding `na.rm=TRUE` you provide an additional argument to `length` that it does not have. It only has one argument `x`.

Comment: you're right: I thought `na.rm` was relaed to the main function and not `length`. thanks! I found out that the error `[aggregate] this function does not return the correct number of values` lied in the fact that I was using `fact=gridRes/res(chm)[1]` to create the aggregation factor. Unfortunately `res(chm)` was 1.034m and this led to `fact=19.xxx` instead of the desired `20` (that I avoided in the example above in order n to use undeclared variables).